# width and height of img in html doesn't work

Tags: html, css

my html is below.

```
    <img src="something" alt="" width="1px" height="1px" border="0" />
```

I think it shows image of 1px × 1px.
but actually the code shows below.

```
 <img src="something" alt="" border="0" width="438" height="438" srcset="something?zoom=1.25&amp;resize=438%2C438&amp;" src-orig="something?resize=1%2C1&amp;" scale="1.25">
```

Why do I have the error?
Why does not image of 1px × 1px show on my site?
Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont write `px` try this :

```html
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-7.jpg" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

Actually it should also work with `px`. So what could be the reason that your code isn't working is you are either overwriting the rule with some other `CSS` or `javascript`. Turn off `CSS` and or `javascript` if it still isn't working and see why.

See here if you have added CSS rules it will not work:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-7.jpg" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

Comment: What @caramba mentioned is right. When we use height and width as attribute in tags , we don't mentioned value in pixels. We simply write   `<img src= "someimage.jpg" alt="image" height="100" width="100" > `.  Or we can write it as styling as well. For example:  <img src= "someimage.jpg" alt="image"  style="height:100px;width:100px;" >